# "@required" annotation as error instead of warning

Tags: dart, flutter

Right now in my Flutter project when I annotate a constructor parameter with `@required` and forget it when instantiating the constructor, I get a light warning from my IDE that the parameter is required.

I would like this to show up as an actual error from the IDE. Is there a way in `analysis_options.yaml` or somewhere else to set it as error instead of warning?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `analysis_options.yaml` add

```
analyzer:
  errors:
    missing_required_param: error
```

before

```
 $ flutter analyze
Analyzing flutter_0_generic...                                   

   info • The parameter 'onPressed' is required • lib/main.dart:49:33 • missing_required_param

1 issue found. (ran in 2.2s)
```

after

```
 $ flutter analyze
Analyzing flutter_0_generic...                                   

  error • The parameter 'onPressed' is required • lib/main.dart:49:33 • missing_required_param

1 issue found. (ran in 1.8s)
```

See also https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/analysis-options#changing-the-severity-of-analysis-rules

Comment: Thanks, I will try this out. I would also like to do it for `@protected`, but I don't know what its analyzer option is called. I'm not sure where you found `missing_required_param` either since it is not in the documentation. Is there a list somewhere that I'm missing?

Comment: If you look at the `flutter analyze` output in my answer you see that the name is at the end of the `info` line. You can also get it by copying the line in the AndroidStudio "Dart Analysis" window and paste it into some text window (the result also contains the rule name among other stuff)

Comment: I was just able to test it and it worked. But I do need to note that the Dart Analysis window does not show the name. I have to manually run `flutter analyze` in order to get it. Everything else worked like a charm though.

Comment: I didn't say it does. Select the line, copy and then paste into a text editor window, then it will show.

Comment: Ah yes I see that now. My mistake.