# Flutter (Dart) only gives me a warning instead of an error during a missing required function argument

Tags: flutter, dart

Why does Flutter only give me a warning instead of an error during a missing required function argument?

Let's take this code for example:

```dart
      FlatButton(
        color: Colors.red,
        onPressed: () {
          doSomething();
        },
      ),
```

The FlatButton requires a `@required Widget child` and `@required VoidCallback onPressed` argument. The child is missing here, but it still compiles and only gives me a warning.

Are `@Required` arguments not that important to give an error? Can somebody explain me why this only gives a warning instead of an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@required`, as designated by the `@`, is just an annotation (provided from [`package:meta`](https://pub.dev/packages/meta)) and is not a language feature.  It tells tools such as the Dart *analyzer* to generate a warning, but neglecting to supply the missing argument is still technically legal, so it will compile.

You can [make the Dart analyzer treat it as an error instead of as a warning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54117257/), but again, that won't help if you neglect to run the analyzer.

Note that the null-safe version of Dart adds [a new `required` keyword](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety#required-named-parameters) that replaces the `@required` annotation, and *that* therefore will be a proper language feature and will generate compilation errors if the argument is omitted.